# Neo4j "variable not defined" error in a subquery - cannot see outer variables

Tags: neo4j

The Neo4j subquery appears to not recieve the outer variables `parent1, parent2, parent3`.

Instead it throws an error:

```
Variable `parent1` not defined (line 10, column 8 (offset: 282))
"  WITH parent1, parent2, parent3"
```

`parent1` is very clearly defined above. This error only occurs if I use the `EXISTS` clause.

My minimal breaking script is below:

```
// using three extant nodes, merge a child node
// THe child should only be created if the whole pattern doesnt exist

MERGE (parent1:Parent1 {parent1id: 0})
MERGE (parent2:Parent2 {parent2id: 0})
MERGE (parent3:Parent3 {parent3id: 0})

WITH parent1, parent2, parent3
CALL {
  WITH parent1, parent2, parent3
  WHERE NOT EXISTS{MATCH (parent2)-->(matched: Child {childi: 0})<--(parent1), (parent3)-->(matched)}
  RETURN 1 as result
}
RETURN *
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are variables well-defined in a `MERGE` clause? I had thought you needed a `MATCH` clause to do that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Try inserting a `MATCH` in-between the last `MERGE` and the `WITH` clause.

Comment: But if I’ve merged, then the nodes should always exist. What do you mean by well defined?

Comment: Yes, the nodes should exist, but the variable names you've previously defined might no longer be in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// using three extant nodes, merge a child node
// THe child should only be created if the whole pattern doesnt exist

MERGE (parent1:Parent1 {parent1id: 0})
MERGE (parent2:Parent2 {parent2id: 0})
MERGE (parent3:Parent3 {parent3id: 0})

MATCH (parent1:Parent1 {parent1id: 0})
WITH parent1
MATCH (parent2:Parent2 {parent2id: 0})
WITH parent1, parent2
MATCH (parent3:Parent3 {parent3id: 0})
WITH parent1, parent2, parent3
CALL {
  WITH parent1, parent2, parent3
  WHERE NOT EXISTS{MATCH (parent2)-->(matched: Child {childi: 0})<--(parent1), (parent3)-->(matched)}
  RETURN 1 as result
}
RETURN *
```

I think the issue is that a `MERGE` command is a sort of "finishing" clause, and variables go out-of-scope after it.

Comment: Try with more WITH clauses, like the edit.